# How to Find Duplicates from 2 Linked Tables?

Tags: mysql

```
Table 1 : Contacts
Fields : id | first_name | last_name

Table 2 : email (it contains contact_id of contacts table)
Fields : id | contact_id | email_address
```

I need to find duplicate contacts based on `first_name`,`last_name` and `email_address`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT R.first_name , R.last_name, S.email_address 
FROM Table1 R
INNER JOIN Table2 S ON R.id = S.Contactid
Group By R.first_name , R.last_name, S.email_address
Having Count(S.Contactid)>1;
```